# Erro transição de imagem Slide em JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou montando um site e o slide de imagens não está funcionando.. a imagem fica estática. O que pode ser?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tema.css">
 
 <!-- JQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Slide -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function slideSwitch() {
   var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

   if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

   // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
   var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

   // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order
   
   // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
   // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
   // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


   $active.addClass('last-active');

   $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
     $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
  }

  $(function() {
   setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
  });
 </script>
 
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
 <!-- Menu -->
 
 <!-- Carrosel -->
 <div id="slideshow">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
  <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
  <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
  <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
 </div>
 
 <!-- Corpo do Site -->
 <div class='container-fluid'>
 

 </div>

 <!-- Rodapé -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remova o `jquery-3.2.1.slim` e utilize a versão "completa". A versão `slim` não vem com a função `animate`

Comment: @LucasFonseca, Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já está utilizando o `bootstrap`, ele tem um componente pronto para isso, basta você implementar a estrutura e atribuir as classes corretamente

```css
#slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tema.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Menu -->

  <!-- Carrosel -->
  <div id="slideshow" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://i.imgur.com/SZPjHwz.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C8lePKsXcAAt5Fc.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item ">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DLeU9xCVwAAbjM8.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/88d89612db5eaacc6c9c6ac6bf6cd6e7/tenor.gif?itemid=7715402" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Corpo do Site -->
  <div class='container-fluid'></div>

  <!-- Rodapé -->

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Referência](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)